# forwarding HDMI signal from PC to monitor via VDI

Tags: hdmi, raspberry-pi

Is following setup possible:

Connect raspberry PI to PC via HDMI cable.
Transfer HDMI signal from PC to monitor via VDI and display raspberry PI GUI on monitor.

My monitor does not have a HDMI port, so i guess if above setup is not possible, ill have to buy an adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. You will need to buy an adapter... Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1PZQTS).

With that being said, I am not sure that the **audio** will be converted/transmitted through that adapter. I have seen a couple posts with varying outcomes.

Good luck!

EDIT: I just wanted to add that those adapters can be found at your local electronics store (like Best Buy) and are rather inexpensive. Mentioning this so you don't have to wait days to play your Pi :D